# IOS XML Parser for IPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I new in XML parsing. I am totaly cofused **how many methods we should have to require for xml parsing and what does use of that method**.

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="q">title:ios</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="3" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="author">Boney, James</str>
            <str name="author-letter">Boney, James</str>
            <arr name="collection">
                <str>Catalog</str>
            </arr>
            <arr name="ctrlnum">
                <str>(DE-599)BSZ096485965</str>
            </arr>
            <arr name="dewey-full">
                <str>004.62</str>
                <str>004.6/2</str>
            </arr>
            <arr name="dewey-hundreds">
                <str>
000 - Informatik, Informationswissenschaft, allgemeine Werke
                </str>
            </arr>
```

Now please is there anybody help to find out that, how can i get those informations from the `xml` data using `NSXMLParser` or any other `xml parser` in IOS?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to improve your parsing without using NSXMLParser (because as it is a SAX parser, it is a little bit confusing), use a DOM parser, like KissXML, TouchXML. Also learn about how to use Xpaths, which are string you can use to get xml objects. Like, you if give a command like "//doc" you will get all the xml tags .

Answer (score 0):

`NSXMLParser` is just fine to parse XML files, and you don't really need any other third-party stuff to do this. [NSXMLParser Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html) is really good and clear enough, explaining everything you need in detail. [SeismicXML](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html) is also a good sample code you can use to study and understand it.

[This](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) is also very helpful.

However, to put it in a nutshell, to parse an XML file that's residing somewhere on the Internet, you need two main things:

1. `NSURLConnection`

   You use this to connect to the URL for the XML file, download the data, and save it.
2. `NSXMLParser`

   Once the XML data is downloaded, you use `NSXMLParser` to parse the data and store the parsed stuff in an array or whatever that you need.

Therefore, you need to add `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` and `<NSXMLParserDelegate>` in your `.h` file.

The `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol defines the optional methods implemented by delegates of `NSXMLParser` objects.

These are the delegate methods to handle XML:

```
– parserDidStartDocument:
– parserDidEndDocument:
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
– parser:didStartMappingPrefix:toURI:
– parser:didEndMappingPrefix:
– parser:resolveExternalEntityName:systemID:
– parser:parseErrorOccurred:
– parser:validationErrorOccurred:
– parser:foundCharacters:
– parser:foundIgnorableWhitespace:
– parser:foundProcessingInstructionWithTarget:data:
– parser:foundComment:
– parser:foundCDATA:
```

Depending on what you're doing, you'll pick and use just a few of these, apart from `– parserDidStartDocument:` and `– parserDidEndDocument:` that need to be used. `– parser:parseErrorOccurred:` should also be included.

See [`NSXMLParserDelegate` Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.